# Table auto scrolls when its cells are larger than body width and height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I been working on a web application containing more than 100 tables like this one :-

Some of those tables have many cells that get out of my page and scroll the whole page and destroy its design and some not.

I want to use jquery to auto scroll this table x and y only when its cells are larger than my page width and height.  The scroll works only in this case.  I tried using **css** but it makes the tables that have no scroll problems look so ugly.

Can any one help please

```
<table class="DisplayTable table  table-striped table-images table-bordered" id="FormTable">
<tbody><tr>
  <th nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableHeaders"><a href="/noms/tx_flag_confirmed.php?ob=FromPOP">From POP</a></th>
  <th nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableHeaders"><a href="/noms/tx_flag_confirmed.php?ob=ToPOP">To POP</a></th>
  <th nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableHeaders"><a href="/noms/tx_flag_confirmed.php?ob=TxType">Tx Type</a></th>
  <th nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableHeaders"><a href="/noms/tx_flag_confirmed.php?ob=Customer">Customer</a></th>
  <th nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableHeaders"><a href="/noms/tx_flag_confirmed.php?ob=FromPOP">Date Available</a></th>
  <th nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableHeaders"><a href="/noms/tx_flag_confirmed.php?ob=UserRequired">Required By</a></th>
  <th nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableHeaders"><a href="/noms/tx_flag_confirmed.php?ob=RequestNumber">Request Number</a></th>
 <tr onclick="Highlight(this, '', '#fff')">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">RODA ... C-EG</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">MARAZIQ ... GZ-EG</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">GBEthernet</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">SDHProtect-MSAN-Payload-3-STM1</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">18-Feb-2015</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">ahmed.mabdelsatar</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">ORD-130745-Y1X9M6</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">5620073</td><td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">No</td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">
    <input type="text" onfocus="blur()" size="8" maxlength="11" name="DCD_35671" id="DCD_35671">&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:NewCal('DCD_35671','ddmmmyyyy')">
    <img width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date" src="images/cal.gif"></a></td>
  <td nowrap="nowrap" class="DisplayTableCells">
   <input type="hidden" value="35671" name="id"><input type="hidden" value="1421587294" name="DateRequired">
   <input type="submit" border="0" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I have also formatted your html.  You should do this yourself next time.  Not just for posting here, but in your normal usage.

I note that the html is misformed.  Please peruse it and ensure that the typo is just in the post.  That it is not the cause of your problems.  I am referring to line 10 with in unfinished <th

Comment: yes i fix it thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function to determine an element's height.

For example:

```
var tableHeight = $('table').height();
var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
```

Then, you'll need to work out your logic to make the scroll based on these values.

Comment: somthing like this     $(document).ready(function () {
    var HeightDiv = $("div").height();
    var HeightTable = $("table").height();
    if (HeightTable > HeightDiv) {
        var FontSizeTable = parseInt($("table").css("font-size"), 10);
        while (HeightTable > HeightDiv && FontSizeTable > 5) {
            FontSizeTable--;
            $("table").css("font-size", FontSizeTable);
            HeightTable = $("table").height();
        }
    }
});